# Asp.net commands still running ? but why?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005

I have this scenario :

[image]

When a.aspx loads - I press the button1.

here is the question :

After pressing button1 - I **Close** the browser.

what happens now to the `long work` now ?

I guess it continues...

But the question is why ?

Doesnt Long work knows that his main ancestor thread was terminated ?

in fact also his father thread was terminated also  ( b.aspx thread)

isnt there **any** relationship between long func to b.aspx / a.aspx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a WebRequest to access b.aspx, you're actually making an HTTP GET for that page. B.aspx does not know anything about a.aspx's threads. However, when you close the browser, the HTTP channel from your browser to web server (running your button click handler) is terminated. The web server does not immediately notice this, however, and the thread responding to your click event continues to wait for the b.aspx WebRequest to complete and ultimately waits for your long-running b.aspx to render until server timeouts elapse.

Answer (score 2):

The server stops only when it finished the function button1_Click even if you close.
The thread didn't terminated when you close the browser, the server only know you made a request to run the function button1_Click it doesn't know if the browser still running or not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no implied relationship between your button click and your b.aspx page. In order for cancellation of a long running thread you would need some kind of identifier to be immediately returned to your click method. You would also need to detect the closing of the browser (not possible in all browsers the last time I tried it about 5 years ago). You would then need to somehow cancel that "request" using the previously returned identifier.

It seems to me that b.aspx should really be a webservice, but you would still have to figure out how to cancel an "in-progess" request.

There is no baked-in way of doing this. It does sound like an interesting "developer day" though :)

Answer (score 1):

When you close the browser, or navigate to a new page, the TCP connection is closed, but that by itself doesn't cause the associated thread to be terminated.

You can look to see if the TCP connection is still alive before starting a long-running activity by checking `this.Response.IsClientConnected`. You might also break up a long-running activity into multiple smaller chunks, and check `IsClientConnected` between each one.